# javascript do something only once

Tags: javascript

i have the following function which lets my elements bounce every time i click on them. how can i achive that i can only click once on each element and if i click a second time to get an alert ("already clicked me")?

```
// Bounce On Click
function bounceOnClick(view) {

    // If the view is a normal view (not a scrollview)
    if (view instanceof View) {

        // Listen to a click event
        view.on("click", function (event) {

            // Stop sending the click event to underlying views after this
            event.stopPropagation()

            // "Wind up" the spring
            view.scale = 0.7

            // And scale back to full size with a spring curve
            view.animate({
                properties: {
                    scale: 1.0
                },
                curve: "spring(1000,15,500)"
            })
        })
    }
}
// Loop through all the exported views
for (var layerGroupName in PSD) {
    bounceOnClick(PSD[layerGroupName]);
}
```

Comment: Set a boolean property to the element on click. [eg view.clicked = true; ] If the property exists give an alert. then the 2nd click onwards the alert msg will be generated.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript all objects are dynamic, so you can add properties to view:

```
view.on("click", function (event) {
    if (this.clicked) {
        alert("already clicked!");
    } else {
        // your code
        this.clicked = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
function bounceOnClick(view) {
    if (view instanceof View) {

        // Listen to a click event, and run this handler only once.
        view.one("click", function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            view.scale = 0.7;
            view.animate({
                properties: {
                    scale: 1.0
                },
                curve: "spring(1000,15,500)"
            })

            // New event handler: notify the user the element was clicked before.
            view.on("click", function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                alert("already clicked me!");
            })
        })
    }
}
```

This uses jQuery's [**`.one()`** event handler](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to run the first function only once, and then assigns a new event handler with the `"already clicked me!"` alert.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

**Jquery .one()** :- Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.

Try this :

```
 view.one("click", function (event) {
 // Your Code
 });
```